# C++ Run Program and Tcp server

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I want to run a application (lets say a counter). 
And let tcp clients get the counter number over and tcp connection.

I like the c++ tcp server implementation on this site
http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm

But the problem is that the program freezes 
While waiting for a client.
So the counter won't increment.

How do I run an application and at the same time run a socket ?

- multi threading ?

In this case I prefer the counter as main application and the tcp-server as "exetention"-thread.

Comment: Search for and read about *non-blocking sockets* and *socket polling*.

Comment: Add blocking / non-blocking operations as well to the list

Comment: Read this http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/01_intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a look at this git repo: [tacopie](https://github.com/Cylix/tacopie).

It has these features:

- c++11 style
- async
- multi-platform

and so on.

I think it's a good project to read.